# Java - Connect to remote VM and copy the files

Tags: java, docker, containers

I am currently working on a use case where a remote VM is having some Zip files stored in a specific location, a java containerized application (java application running in Docker container) will connect to this remote VM and copy the files to the internal storage location.

I have 2 questions here:

1. Is it possible to connect to a Windows system remotely by using Java
       libs?
2. Is it possible to use the internal storage location for an application written in Java?
3. How to use the internal container storage (Docker container) in Java application?

Thanks in advance.

Avinash Deshmukh

Comment: I would look into accesing SMB shares from Java using jcifs https://www.jcifs.org/

Comment: @Shloim Thanks for suggesting this. I will try it and let you know.